# How use web-mode with elixir .ex files?

Tags: web-mode

I'm using elixir-mode in the `.ex` file below, but I'd like to be in web-mode while inside the `~L"""` inline template. How to configure web-mode to do this?

[image]

Comment: I think you can use the [mmm-mode package](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/mmm-mode.html) for this, but I have never used it before. However, instructions are given in its info file (for example, for interactive usage see section 1.3 [here](http://xemacs.sourceforge.net/Documentation/packages/html/mmm_1.html#SEC4)).

Comment: @dalanicolai I tried mmm-mode following [these instructions](https://elixirforum.com/t/tips-syntax-highlight-for-inline-l-liveview-code-in-emacs/26445) but it only provided highlighting, no other web-mode functions.

Comment: Too bad. I could not find another easy alternative to achieve it. You might want to use an indirect buffer then, or [narrow-indirect.el](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28212/26163)