# Multiple Independent Views of the Same File

Tags: buffers, indirect-buffers

I can C-x 2 to view the same file in two buffers, but if I for example do this with an org file, then collapse the top heading, this also messes with the first buffer;)

Can I open an independent view of the same file? If I change it, the other buffer will revert like it always does when I save in some external program.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this wasn't a duplicate question, but I don't have time now to look for it.

Comment: @Drew -> https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28203/can-i-have-two-views-on-a-file-one-narrowed-one-not/28205#28205

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have two views on a file - one narrowed one not?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28203/can-i-have-two-views-on-a-file-one-narrowed-one-not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
M-x clone-indirect-buffer-other-window
```

More details at: (emacs)Top > Buffers > Indirect Buffers.